# Can I remove the clip of the iPod nano 6G?

Tags: ipod, hardware, customization, ipod-nano

Is there a (non-brute-force) way to remove the clip-part of the iPod nano 6G? I find, I don't use it and it add clunkiness. Also it's a bit scratched since it's the only part not protected by a silicone wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's very tricky.

You have to disassemble the whole iPod nano as the **[guide for clip removal on iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPod-Nano-6th-Generation-Clip/3605/1)** shows.

This is a picture taken from the second last step:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. But way too fancy for me :)